# Double Click inside DataRow in C#

Tags: c#, datagrid, dataview

I created a DataGrid in C#. It reads and displays the data. But I have a problem on Double clicking part. If I double click on the Text it works and opens but if I double click inside the same row where there is no Text doesn't work. Can somebody help me to solve this problem. Here is the code and a screen shot from program.

[image: Data Grid]

```
    public void FillListBox(DataTable table)
    {
        CgmTable = new DataView(table, "", "Title ASC", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows).ToTable();
        dgCgm.DataSource = CgmTable;          
        dgCgm.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
        dgCgm.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
    }

    private void txtFilter_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
        if (txtFilter.Text.Length == 0 && txtTitle.Text.Length == 0)
            dgCgm.DataSource = CgmTable;
        else
        {
            String sql = tb.Name == "txtTitle" ? "Title LIKE '{0}*'" : "FileName LIKE '{0}*'";
            DataTable table = new DataView(CgmTable, String.Format(sql, tb.Text), "Title asc", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
                .ToTable();
            dgCgm.DataSource = table;               
        }
    }

    private void dgCgm_CellContentDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        int recNo = Convert.ToInt32(dgCgm.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["RecNo"].Value);
        int fileRec = Convert.ToInt32(dgCgm.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["FileRec"].Value);
        string fileName = dgCgm.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["FileName"].Value.ToString();
        string projectName = dgCgm.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Project"].Value.ToString();
        EventHandler<JumpToEventArgs> handler = LaunchCgm;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            JumpToEventArgs ev = new JumpToEventArgs(recNo, fileRec, fileName, projectName);
            handler(this, ev);
        }
        this.Close();
    }       
}

public class JumpToEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    private int recNo, fileRec;
    private string fileName, projectName;        

    public JumpToEventArgs(int recNo, int fileRec, 
        string fileName, string projectName)
    {
        this.recNo = recNo;
        this.fileRec = fileRec;
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.projectName = projectName;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `CellDoubleClick` event ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.celldoubleclick(v=vs.100).aspx)).

Differences between `CellDoubleClick` and `CellContentDoubleClick`:

*DataGridView.CellDoubleClick Event* ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.celldoubleclick%28v=vs.100%29.aspx))

> Occurs when the user double-clicks anywhere in a cell.

*DataGridView.CellContentDoubleClick Event* ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellcontentdoubleclick%28v=vs.100%29.aspx))

> Occurs when the user double-clicks a cell's contents.

You should add event handler to `CellDoubleClick` event and delete event handler from `CellContentDoubleClick`  event:

[image]

Comment: _Do I only need to change cellContentDoubleClick to CellDoubleClick? or is there anything else needs to be changed inside the method? Cause by just changing from ContentDoubleClick to DoubleClick didn't solve the problem @kmatyaszek_

Comment: @user603948 check my answer again :)

Answer (score 1):

The `Content` part of the event is the issue here.  Try using the non-content version:

```
private void dgCgm_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem looks like you are using the wrong event handler. The event handler `CellContentDoubleClick` only fires when the CONTENTS (in your case, the text) of the cell are clicked. Changing the event handler to `CellDoubleClick` will cause the event to fire every time anywhere in the cell is clicked.

Then in the properties window you would have to change the datagridview's `CellDoubleClick` to this method `dgCgm_CellContentDoubleClick`. Or go to the designer code and remove

```
dgCgm.CellContentDoubleClick += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dgCgm_CellContentDoubleClick);
```

And add:

```
dgCgm.CellDoubleClick += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dgCgm_CellContentDoubleClick);
```